# Find out who started my assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

My assembly (.net exe) is typically started with "Assembly.Load(pathname)". Inside the loaded assembly I would like to get access to the assembly which launched my assembly. Is there a chance?

Comment: You *could* pass a command line argument from the assembly that started your assembly and use that to identify the launcher.

Comment: Does your calling assembly call any methods or create any instances inside the loaded assembly?

Comment: Don't use a backdoor to get what you easily find out in a 100% reliable way.  Whatever code loads your assembly can also tell your code what it needs to know, simply by assigning a public property.  The backdoor gets you into trouble when the jitter inlines methods in the Release build.  A constructor with an argument forces the code to do the right thing.

Comment: Sometimes you need backdoor actions, when the caller isn't cooperative. I know it can be hacked.

Comment: @Rotem: Yes, the caller instantiates objects and uses reflection to call methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx).

Comment: This is correct only if the calling chain is one level deep. If assembly A is the entry assembly, which then loaded assembly B, which then in turn loaded assembly C, `GetEntryAssembly` would return assembly A from assembly C, instead of assembly B.

Comment: Well, I guess he could use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` then.

Comment: Yes, EntryAssembly is doing the Job. Thank you!